# What does warning in glmmTMB mean? "failed to invert Hessian from numDeriv"

Tags: glmmtmb, glmm

I am running a big GLMM with `glmmTMB` and am wondering what this warning means? I did not see any info about it in the package troubleshooting. Warning:

> In finalizeTMB(TMBStruc, obj, fit, h, data.tmb.old) :
> failed to invert Hessian from numDeriv::jacobian(), falling back to internal vcov estimate

Would it be bad to proceed and ignore this issue, proceeding with  a `drop1`?

This large GLMM has quadratic terms and their interactions. Taking out some interactions and or/ terms helped solve this.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** `drop1()` should be fine, although this warning should alert you to the fact that the fit may be numerically unstable/computed standard errors may be unreliable.

There are (at least) two ways to compute the covariance matrix of the estimated coefficients (which is used to get the standard errors, p-values, etc. of the individual coefficients). In either case we have to estimate the *Hessian*, the matrix of second derivatives of the negative log-likelihood with respect to the parameters, then find its inverse.

Internally, the TMB package uses the base-R function `optimHess()`, which computes finite differences of the gradient function (see [here](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Akaskr%2Fadcomp%20optimHess&type=code)). `glmmTMB` tries to use `numDeriv::jacobian()` instead, which uses [Richardson extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_extrapolation), which should *in theory* be more accurate.

The warning is saying that inverting the Hessian computed by `numDeriv::jacobian()` failed, and that the `optimHess` version is being used instead.

`drop1()` is using the likelihood ratio test to compare nested models; it is independent of the estimate of the covariance matrix.